# Using regex on Charfield in Django

Tags: python, regex, django, types

I have a model with

```
class dbf_att(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

And i'd like to check later that object.name match some regex:

```
    if re.compile('^\d+$').match(att.name):
        ret = 'Integer'
    elif re.compile('^\d+\.\d+$').match(att.name):
        ret = 'Float'
    else:
        ret = 'String'
  return ret
```

This always return 'String' when some of the att.name should match those regex.

Thanks!

Comment: Your att.name might have a line break such as '\n\r' or whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex are great, but sometimes it is more simpler and readable to use other approaches. For example, How about just using builtin types to check for the type

```
try:
    att_name = float(att.name)
    ret = "Integer" if att_name.is_integer() else "Float"
except ValueError:
    ret = "String"
```

FYI, your regex code works perfectly fine. You might want to inspect the data that is being checked.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = re.compile('^\d+$')
>>> b = re.compile('^\d+\.\d+$')
>>> a.match('10')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10fe7eb28>
>>> a.match('10.94')
>>> b.match('10')
>>> b.match('10.94')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10fe7eb90>
>>> a.match("string")
>>> b.match("string")
```

Comment: Using this way, it still always return string. Do you know a way to print this att.name easily to check if it's correct?

Comment: This means that the `att.name` is most likely a string. Can you look in the database to see the value ? Also in your local server, `print att.name` should print the value to the  console.

Comment: Hmm yes, att.name is actually the name of the table is the db and not the data. I'll try to see why tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [RegexValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/#regexvalidator)

Or you can to it with package [django-regex-field](https://github.com/ambitioninc/django-regex-field), but i would rather recommand you to use built-in solution, the less third-party-apps the better.